# Need to sum same group of items in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a items with same batch need to update items stock. When below query execute then only one item batch stock is added to stock.Need to group same group of items. Currently issue below query only add once if same items record exist two time. How to group by and sum in case statement.

```
UPDATE si
SET si.iCurrentStock = si.iCurrentStock + 
                          (CASE 
                              WHEN  ttd.vEffectType = 'Add' THEN ttd.iLeafQuantity
                              WHEN ttd.vEffectType = 'Subtract' THEN ttd.iLeafQuantity * -1 
                              ELSE 0 
                           END),
     ttd.bIsStockUpdated = 1
FROM dbo.tblStoreItem si
INNER JOIN dbo.tblTransactionDetail ttd ON si.iItemId = ttd.iItemId
WHERE si.iStoreId = @v_StoreId
  AND ttd.iTransactionId = @p_TransactionId
  AND ISNULL(ttd.bIsStockUpdated, 0) = 0;



ItemId:1  Cost:500  BatchNumber:111 Quantity:200
ItemId:1  Cost:500  BatchNumber:222 Quantity:300
ItemId:1  Cost:200  BatchNumber:333 Quantity:100
```

Six hundred items quantity must be added to current stock but above query only added 200 quantity.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results as text.

Comment: You did see the comment "as text" right? Please don't use images for code, data or errors.

Comment: You need to pre-group `tblTransactionDetail` by `ItemId`, then join it to `tblStoreItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information, you probably need something like:

```
UPDATE si
SET si.iCurrentStock = si.iCurrentStock + 
(
    SELECT
        SUM(
                          (CASE 
                              WHEN  ttd2.vEffectType = 'Add' THEN ttd2.iLeafQuantity
                              WHEN ttd2.vEffectType = 'Subtract' THEN ttd2.iLeafQuantity * -1 
                              ELSE 0 
                           END)
        )
    FROM tblTransactionDetail ttd2
    WHERE ttd2.iTransactionId = @p_TransactionId
    AND ISNULL(ttd2.bIsStockUpdated, 0) = 0
)
,
     ttd.bIsStockUpdated = 1
FROM dbo.tblStoreItem si
INNER JOIN dbo.tblTransactionDetail ttd ON si.iItemId = ttd.iItemId
WHERE si.iStoreId = @v_StoreId
  AND ttd.iTransactionId = @p_TransactionId
  AND ISNULL(ttd.bIsStockUpdated, 0) = 0;
```

Comment: Error The multi-part identifier could not be bound si.iCurrentStock

Comment: Sorry. On phone. Try the edited version

Comment: still have same error but now on ttd.bIsStockUpdated

Comment: Cant see whats wrong. Maybe try commenting out the ttd.bIsStockUpdated = 1 and see if that fixes it. At least ot proves that is the problem